# Extract number between html tags

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk, grep

I want to extract two type of numbers between HTML tags:

```
>******</a></td>
```

`*****` is a number with variable length [0-9]{1,5} and can be separeted via comma "311,3454" (the comma is also necessary)

What would be the best way to extract these numbers? Awk, sed, grep?

Comment: anything you want to use , understand and be able to code!

Comment: The best way would be to make use of a XML parser.  You might want to take a look at `xmllint`.

Comment: If you want to only allow one optional comma (ie. a pair of integers) and have the number start with an actual digit: `<([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:\s+[^>]+)?>([0-9]+(?!.*,.*,)[0-9,]*)<\/\1>`, then access capture group 2.

Comment: Thanks guys, especially thanks for the xmllint suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` can do it:

```
grep -Po '(?<=>)[0-9,]*(?=</a></td>)' file
```

It fetches the combination of numbers and commas in between `>` and `</a></td>`.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
>234,23</a></td>
>234,23</b></td>

$ grep -Po '(?<=>)[0-9,]*(?=</a></td>)' a
234,23
```

Comment: Thank you, I must learn some more regexp in the future! :) <a> should be a closing tag </a>

Comment: You are right, just updated! Nice to read it worked to you :)